# Stopping times and expectation for the symmetric random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $X_n : \Omega \to \{ -1, 1 \}$ be a random variable with $P(X = -1) = P(X = 1) = 1/2$, like tossing a coin, and $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_n$. Also let $\tau_m : \Omega \to \mathbb N \cup \{ \infty\}$ be the stopping time $\tau_m(\omega) := \inf\{ n : M_n(\omega) = m \}$ and $S_n = 4 \cdot 2^{M_n}$. I want to evaluate for $m > 0$
$$
 E\left[ \left( \frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{\tau_{-m}} (K - S_{\tau_{-m}})\right]
$$
where $K \in \mathbb R$ and $r > 0$ are some numbers. In my textbook we have
$$
  E\left[ \left( \frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{\tau_{-m}} (K - S_{\tau_{-m}})\right]
   = 4(1 - 2^{-m}) E\left[ \left( \frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{\tau_{-m}} \right].
$$
I understand that this holds if $\tau_{-m}(\omega) < \infty$, but what if $\tau_{-m}(\omega) = \infty$, i.e. we never have $M_n(\omega) = m$? Then this expression does not make any sense at all?

Remark: For context, this is from the book [Stochastic Calculus for Finance I](https://books.google.de/books?id=j_S3KZNFFrkC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=policy%201%20exercise%20the%20first%20time%20the%20stock%20price%20falls%20to%20the%20level&source=bl&ots=G0jYoLoRlS&sig=VC5Bs0v2pkR_vGHMcCmwag2kKdE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMI_daD8I2QxgIVy8AUCh1LJgCw#v=onepage&q=policy%201%20exercise%20the%20first%20time%20the%20stock%20price%20falls%20to%20the%20level&f=false), I linked the relevant part from Google books.

Comment: The way to interpret the formula is that if $\tau_{-m}=\infty$, which happens with possibly some positive probability, then $1/(1+r)^{\tau_{-m}}=0$

Comment: @AlexR.: In this case, since simple random walk is recurrent, we have $\tau_{-m} < \infty$ almost surely, so you can really interpret the expression any way you want and it makes no difference.